# Why do I have 495.5 MB of ram?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

So as far as I know, Ram comes in sticks of (In MB) 256, 512, 1024 and so on. For some reason my one stick of ram is being registered both by bios and the OS as 495.5 MB. It should be mentioned that I don't know the exact capacity of the ram stick, but I do think this number is odd. Is something wrong with my ram? Will it negatively impact performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you use an onboard GPU which uses some of the main RAM?

Comment: there is a gpu integrated into the cpu, (pentium 4) but I don't belive there is one attached to the motherboard. I am currently using an nvidia 8400 in a PCI-e slot

Comment: go to the BIOS and look if you can disable the integrated GPU.

Comment: I can't, I can only set preference of which to use (currently set to pcie) although maybe, doing that disables the integrated gpu since there is no longer output from the onboard vga port?

Comment: If you can't disable it, why did you accept the answer, that suggest you disabled it?

Comment: Because it answered the question "Why do I have 495.5 MB of ram?"

Comment: Correct Moab. I'm mainly concerned about if my ram is defective, not about having the extra 16.5 MB of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of RAM is displayed is less, than what you have installed, when you have an integrated graphics processor (on-board GPU).

If you're not using it, you could, from the motherboard settings*:

1. Disable the on-board graphics card.
2. Reduce the amount of RAM your system reserves for the GPU.

**Whichever settings are available. Most motherboards should at least have either of the two.*

After that it should show 512 MB.